# Conversion to Glimmer components – dynamic property in service

Tags: ember.js, glimmer.js

I am trying to build a Glimmer component that reacts to changes to properties in a service, see below where I am trying to make the component to update the get playing in response to changes in the audioPlayer url and status – which are changed when the play button is pressed in the play action below.... This is not working, and I haven’t been able to find any documentation to support this type of behaviour.

```
import { action } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service'; 

export default class ShowAudioEpisodeComponent extends Component {
  
  @service audioPlayer;
  
  get playing() {
    return this.audioPlayer.url == this.args.epi.audioUrl && this.audioPlayer.status == "playing";
  }

  @action
  play() {
    if (this.playing) {
      this.audioPlayer.pause(this.args.epi);
    } else {
      this.audioPlayer.playEpisode(this.args.epi);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: is `audioPlayer.url` marked as tracked?

Comment: No, and not sure the syntax for that if necessary?

Comment: You need to tell Ember that the property can change. Otherwise derived state in getters like `get playing() {}` and usage in template will not be updated if it changes. Please find more details in the guides: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/component-state-and-actions/ and https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/tracked-properties/

Answer (score 2):

The `audio-player` service must declare `url` and `status` as [`@tracked`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.20/functions/@glimmer%2Ftracking/tracked), OR must always update them using [`set`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fobject/set)

Comment: Thanks Luke, I will try this out when I have time and see if I can get it working that way!